# How to find the nearest location of array of latlng to my location and front of me not behind me

Tags: java, android, location, distance, locationlistener

Hello everyone I am developing an android application , while the device moving there is a saved location (latlng object ) in array , I want it to alert user of nearest place from his device , but it maybe the nearest place behind hem not front of hem ,  like the figure here : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHEBP.png)

here is the list of location

```
List<LatLng> cameraLocation = new ArrayList<>();
```

and here how i calculate the distance

```
  for (LatLng location : cameraLocation) {
                    closestCamera = location;
                    smallestDistance = distance;
                    Log.e("distanceTest", distance + "");
                    Log.d("closestCamera" , location+"" );
                    distanceList.add(CalculationByDistance(myLocation, location));
                    distance = Collections.min(distanceList);

                }
```

the CalculationByDistance function is like this

```
public double CalculationByDistance(LatLng StartP, LatLng EndP) {
        int Radius = 6371;// radius of earth in Km
        double lat1 = StartP.latitude;
        double lat2 = EndP.latitude;
        double lon1 = StartP.longitude;
        double lon2 = EndP.longitude;
        double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
        double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
        double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2)
                + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1))
                * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLon / 2)
                * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
        double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
        double valueResult = Radius * c;
        double km = valueResult / 1;
        DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("#");
        int kmInDec = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(km));
        double meter = valueResult % 1000;
        int meterInDec = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(meter));
        Log.i("Radius Value", "" + valueResult + "   KM  " + kmInDec
                + " Meter   " + meterInDec);

        return Radius * c;
    }
```

any help please ..

Comment: Where do you get `myLocation` from?

Comment: GPS .... LatLng  myLocation = new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude()); .... where loc is Location object .

Comment: I have updated answer with example code.

Answer (score 0):

You could have two `Location` instances in your class, first `currentLocation` and second `lastLocation`. Calculate distance of your `place` from `currentLocation` and `lastLocation`. is the distance between `currentLocation` and your `place` is `greater` than the distance between `lastLocation` and your `place`, than you are moving away from that `place`. i.e that place is behind your current location.

Example Code:

```
private Location currentLocation;
private Location lastLocation;

public void onLocationUpdate(Location location){
    lastLocation = currentLocation;
    currentLocation = location;
    calculateDistance();
}

private double smallestDistance;
private LatLng closestCamera;
private void calculateDistance(){
    for (LatLng location : cameraLocation) {
        double distanceFromLastLocation = CalculationByDistance(new LatLng(lastLocation.lat, lastLocation.lng), location);
        double distanceFromCurrentLocation = CalculationByDistance(new LatLng(lastLocation.lat, lastLocation.lng), location);
        if (distanceFromCurrentLocation < distanceFromLastLocation) {
            continue; // User is going away from location i.e location is behind user. No need to calculate distance between user and cameraLocation.
        }
        distanceList.add(CalculationByDistance(myLocation, location));
        if (Collections.min(distanceList) == distanceFromCurrentLocation) {
            // this location is nearest amongst all the cameraLocations.
            smallestDistance = distanceFromCurrentLocation;
            closestCamera = location;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference >>>>>>  it keep give me that error .. I tried to trice the code but i really don't know where the error ?

Comment: double distanceFromLastLocation = CalculationByDistance(new LatLng(lastLocation.getLatitude(), lastLocation.getLongitude()), location);
                                    double distanceFromCurrentLocation = CalculationByDistance(new LatLng(lastLocation.getLatitude(), lastLocation.getLongitude()), location);

Comment: it came from those above lines